# Context Menu - How can I know which control activated it

Tags: c#, listview, contextmenu, mousedown

I have made a context menu which is activated via `MouseDown`event. This event checks if the user clicked the right button and if so opens the menu. I am using the same event to open the same context menu for a listbox and a listview. Is there a way to check which one of them activated the MouseDown event?

Edit: I'll be a bit more specific. I can tell which controller activated the event from the event itself.. I want to know which controller activated the event from the context menu item which has been clicked on.

Comment: You have to be specific about what class library you are talking about, there's more than one ContextMenu class.  And you'll have to explain what this question has to do with the [listview] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the Tag property of the context menu. I put there the sender object which triggered the event, and then I could just do:

```
ListView lv = resultsContextMenu.Tag as ListView;
if (lv == null) //listbox was the one to call the mouse down event
{ //do stuff }
```

this code was called inside the menu items themselves that were chosen by the user

Answer (score 2):

If you have something like that:

```
private void MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

}
```

you can check `sender`:

```
if(sender is ListView)
{
    //event fired by ListView
} 

if(sender is ListBox)
{
    //event fired by ListBox
}
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I didn't mean that exactly. Please read my edit to the original question since I wasn't clear with what I meant :)